# How do I create an AD username with a dot in it via Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to change an existing script so that my username is firstname intial dot last name
for example: John Doe's username will be j.doe
Current script works (without the .) as:
$firstname.substring(0,$i) + $lastname

thank you.

Comment: the simplest way - for me - is to use the `-f` string format operator. like this >>> `'{0}.{1}' -f 'John'[0], 'Doe'` <<< [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

there are several ways to build that string. [*grin*] here are 4 of them that come to mind for me.

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in a CSV file with FirstName, LastName data
  replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with your preferred data source.
- iterates thru the resulting collection
- builds the desired string with 4 different methods
  my preference is the `-f` string format operator, but many folks prefer string concatenation.
- sends each out to the display
- adds a divider line between the groups of results

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a CSV file
#    when ready to do this for real, use your prefered data source
#    and delete or comment out the entire "#region/#endregion" block
$NameList = @'
FirstName, LastName
Alfa, Bravo
Charlie, Delta
Echo, Foxtrot
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

foreach ($NL_Item in $NameList)
    {
    # string format operator
    '{0}.{1}' -f $NL_Item.FirstName[0], $NL_Item.LastName

    # -join operator
    $NL_Item.FirstName[0], $NL_Item.LastName -join '.'

    # string concatenation
    $NL_Item.FirstName[0] + '.' + $NL_Item.LastName

    # variable-in-string expansion
    "$($NL_Item.FirstName[0]).$($NL_Item.LastName)"

    # yes, you can multiply a string [*grin*] 
    '=' * 20
    }
```

output ...

```
A.Bravo
A.Bravo
A.Bravo
A.Bravo
====================
C.Delta
C.Delta
C.Delta
C.Delta
====================
E.Foxtrot
E.Foxtrot
E.Foxtrot
E.Foxtrot
====================
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstname.substring(0,$i) +"."+ $lastname
```